# prevent queuing of asynctask tasks in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I need to prevent execution of two or more asynctask at the same time, For example:

```
AsyncTask t1 = new myTask();
AsyncTask t2 = new myTask();
AsyncTask t3 = new myTask();
t1.execute();
t2.execute();
t3.ececute();
```

I need t2 and t3 to be canceled and not be executed at all in  case t1 is running.
Is `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` what i need ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()) will run everything on a single thread, i.e. One after the other. The best way to do what you want to do would be to not allow new tasks to be created if current tasks are already running. You can use the following code as example:

```
MyAsyncTask task = new MyAsyncTask();
private void createNewTask(Object o) {
  if(task.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
    //Do Something?
  } else {
    task = new MyAsyncTask();
    task.execute(arg0);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have a similar use case.  Do you know how I can create a singleton instance of the executor so that a new executor is not created for every CRUD operation?

Answer (score 1):

you can check in onPreExecute() of t2 and t3 if t1 is running or not, if it's running then cancel the current(t2 or t3) task.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create an asynctask manager class, that just won't execute an asynctask if one is already executing and just use flags to keep track of, if a current task is executing.

I believe you can control the Thread executor pool as well to force Android to do this but, why rely on that if you don't have.